# How to handle differening parent json keys in postgresql jsonb

Tags: postgresql

I have json records ingested in jsonb format that have varying parent keys i want to access- most of the parent keys refer to a document schema

```
SELECT  id, COALESCE(data->'TEXPORT'->'FORM_SECTION'->'F03_2014',
data->'TEXPORT'->'FORM_SECTION'->'F02_2014',
data->'TEXPORT'->'FORM_SECTION'->'NOTICE_UUID',
data->'TEXPORT'->'FORM_SECTION'->'F01_2014',
data->'TEXPORT'->'FORM_SECTION'->'F14_2014',
data->'TEXPORT'->'FORM_SECTION'->'F21_2014',
data->'TEXPORT'->'FORM_SECTION'->'F15_2014')->'OBJECT'->'SHORT_DESCR'->'P' from json_table
```

How can i make this cleaner and how do i do multiple coalesces? Ie. sometimes the SHORT_DESCR key is called something else also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own helper function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION first_property(value jsonb, VARIADIC keys text[]) RETURNS jsonb AS $$
    SELECT value -> key
    FROM UNNEST(keys) WITH ORDINALITY AS _(key, i)
    WHERE value ? key
    ORDER BY i
    LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

<sub>([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=de7e32e574d3eb3ee106480ff05e9b16))</sub>

With that, you can shorten your query to

```
SELECT
  id,
  first_property(
    data->'TEXPORT'->'FORM_SECTION',
    'F03_2014', 'F02_2014', 'NOTICE_UUID', 'F01_2014', 'F14_2014', 'F21_2014', 'F15_2014'
  )->'OBJECT'->'SHORT_DESCR'->'P'
FROM json_table
```

and you can call it multiple times, like

```
SELECT
  id,
  first_property(
    first_property(
      data->'TEXPORT'->'FORM_SECTION',
      'F03_2014', 'F02_2014', 'NOTICE_UUID', 'F01_2014', 'F14_2014', 'F21_2014', 'F15_2014'
    )->'OBJECT',
    'SHORT_DESCR', 'SDCR', 'DESC'
  )->'P'
FROM json_table
```